# How to disable postgrey from a postfix server?

Tags: email, postfix-mta

I have postgrey installed on a postfix mail server, but I don't want it anymore. I see no option to disable/enable postgrey in postfix. When I uninstall it, the server stops receiving mail.

Do I need to re-install my entire mail server without postgrey or is there a way to simply turn it off?

Comment: I'm not an expert in these so I can't say for sure, but if you want to try and rescue your current configuration I'd either 1) try and diagnose why you're not getting any email when you remove postgrey - look at the logs, look at the rejection message the server gives for incoming mail, etc.; or 2) try and get hold of a clean copy of the postfix configuration e.g. from your distribution's packages or another server, and diff what you've got against that to see if you can see any leftover postgrey configuration (or just grep it for 'postgrey' case insensitively in the first instance)

Comment: It would probably also be useful to know what Linux distribution you're running, and whether you got postgrey from the distribution, in which case maybe install or uninstall scripts provided by them are to blame, or if you installed it from source and uninstalled it yourself - how did you do the uninstall? And possibly the version numbers of all of these if they're not recent.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, Ubuntu and from the apt repo. Uninstall didn't do it. I'm thinking about just rebuilding my server.

Comment: I turned it off with this: 
...in the file: `/etc/postfix/main.c`
...on the line starting with: `smtpd_recipient_restrictions =`
...removed from the line: `check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023`

I don't have enough rep points to answer my own question. Anyone want to take a jab and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I turned it off with this:

in the file: `/etc/postfix/main.cf`...

- on the line starting with: `smtpd_recipient_restrictions =`
- removed `check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023`

Yeah! No reinstall!